# Python/Numpy how to do outer product of two 1-d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two vectors a and b, where the size of a is  (100,) and b is sparse matrix(vector) that has size(1,500). I know that I can use

```
b.toarray().flatten()
```

to get a numpy 1-d array(vector) of shape (500,). Now I want to do a outer product of a and b so that I can get a matrix of size (100, 500).

I have tried using

```
np.transpose(b)
```

to hope to get a vector of dimension (,500). However, it does not work. So could anyone offer some advice about this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `np.outer(a, b)`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It worked, thank you! Did not realize that there is a built in outer product function